# How to parse a JSON object into smaller objects using Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a very large JSON object that I need to split into smaller objects and write those smaller objects to file.

**Sample Data**

```
raw = '[{"id":"1","num":"2182","count":-17}{"id":"111","num":"3182","count":-202}{"id":"222","num":"4182","count":12},{"id":"33333","num":"5182","count":12}]'
```

**Desired Output** (In this example, split the data in half)

```
output_file1.json = [{"id":"1","num":"2182","count":-17},{"id":"111","num":"3182","count":-202}]

output_file2.json = [{"id":"222","num":"4182","count":12}{"id":"33333","num":"5182","count":12}]
```

**Current Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import json
from itertools import zip_longest


def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

    raw = '[{"id":"1","num":"2182","count":-17}{"id":"111","num":"3182","count":-202}{"id":"222","num":"4182","count":12},{"id":"33333","num":"5182","count":12}]'

#split the data into manageable chunks + write to files

for i, group in enumerate(grouper(raw, 4)):
    with open('outputbatch_{}.json'.format(i), 'w') as outputfile:
        json.dump(list(group), outputfile)
```

**Current Output** of first file "outputbatch_0.json"

```
["[", "{", "\"", "s"]
```

I feel like I'm making this much harder than it needs to be.

Comment: Your `raw` string isn't valid JSON (missing commas between objects). Is this the case with your real data or just a typo in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming the raw should be a valid json string (I included the missing commas), here is a simple, but working solution.

```
import json

raw = '[{"id":"1","num":"2182","count":-17},{"id":"111","num":"3182","count":-202},{"id":"222","num":"4182","count":12},{"id":"33333","num":"5182","count":12}]'
json_data = json.loads(raw)

def split_in_files(json_data, amount):
    step = len(json_data) // amount
    pos = 0
    for i in range(amount - 1):
        with open('output_file{}.json'.format(i+1), 'w') as file:
            json.dump(json_data[pos:pos+step], file)
            pos += step
    # last one
    with open('output_file{}.json'.format(amount), 'w') as file:
        json.dump(json_data[pos:], file)

split_in_files(json_data, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

if raw is valid json. the saving part is not detailed.

```
import json

raw = '[{"id":"1","num":"2182","count":-17},{"id":"111","num":"3182","count":-202},{"id":"222","num":"4182","count":12},{"id":"33333","num":"5182","count":12}]'

raw_list = eval(raw)
raw__zipped = list(zip(raw_list[0::2], raw_list[1::2]))

for item in raw__zipped:
    with open('a.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(item, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the exactly half of the data you can use slicing:

```
import json

raw = '[{"id":"1","num":"2182","count":-17},{"id":"111","num":"3182","count":-202},{"id":"222","num":"4182","count":12},{"id":"33333","num":"5182","count":12}]'
json_data = json.loads(raw)

size_of_half = len(json_data)/2

print json_data[:size_of_half]
print json_data[size_of_half:]
```

In shared code basic cases are not handled like what if length is odd etc, In short You can do everything that you can do with list.