# Data inside a JSON has letters and numbers I do not need, how to get data I need in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am looking at extracting data from within a JSON file, but the data I need has numbers and letters before and sometimes after the data. I would like to know if it is possible to remove the unnecessary numbers and letter I do not need. Here is an example of the data:

```
"most_common_aircraft":[{"planned_aircraft":"B738/L","dcount":4592},{"planned_aircraft":"H/B744/L","dcount":3639},{"planned_aircraft":"H/B77L/L","dcount":2579},{"planned_aircraft":"H/B772/L","dcount":1894},{"planned_aircraft":"H/B763/L","dcount":1661},{"planned_aircraft":"H/B748/L","dcount":1303},{"planned_aircraft":"B712/L","dcount":1289},{"planned_aircraft":"B739/L","dcount":1198},{"planned_aircraft":"H/B77W/L","dcount":978},{"planned_aircraft":"B738","dcount":957}]
```

"H/B77L/L , B752/L, A320/X, B738,"

all I am interested in is the main 4 letters/numbers, for example instead of "H/B77L/L" I want just "B77L", instead of "B752/L" I want "B752". The data is very mixed, so some will have a letters in front, some at the end and some with both, then there are others that are already in the correct format I want. Is there a way to remove the additional letters during the extracting of data from a JSON file using Python, if not would it be better as I am using Pandas to extracting them all to a dataframe then compare it to another dataframe which has the correct sequence without the additional letters?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Do you want to modify `most_common_aircraft` or extract data under `planned_aircraft` field and then modify it for further use? Also please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: you check this response here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52388348/how-to-parse-a-json-object-into-smaller-objects-using-python/52388953

Comment: Quamrana, I have not tried any code as I have no idea how to do it.  Ashu Grover, any way would do, but I do also need the "dcount". I do know how to extract data from a JSON  file, but I do not know how to change that data that is within that JSON as indicated in my original question.

Comment: If you are getting the values into a df, you can research regex regular expressions to pull 4 character strings or research split by '/' again looking for 4 character strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find the answer and solve my problem. I will put it here so to help others that may have a similar problem -

```
for entry in json_data['results']:
for value in entry['most_common_aircraft']:
    for splitted_string in value['planned_aircraft'].split('/'):
        if len(splitted_string) == 4:
            value['planned_aircraft'] = splitted_string
```